# Why does this programme not stop after three password guesses?

Tags: python

```
username = "Patrick"

password = "Kearney"



username = input("Username:")

while username != "Patrick":

    print("Please try again.")

    username = input("Enter your username again.")


password = input("Password:")

incorrect = 0

threshold = 3

while password != "Kearney":

        print("Please try again.")

        password = input("Enter your password again.")

if password != "Kearney":

        incorrect += 1
else:
        print("Welcome Patrick")
        incorrect = 0


if incorrect == threshold:

        import sys

        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Please check your formatting. Is what you posted here, how it looks when you run it?

Comment: Thanks, but the programme still asks for the password even after three tries.

Comment: Python scope depends on formatting so it's impossible to say with how your code is posted

Comment: no, i formatted it wrong here

Comment: The loop `while password != "Kearney":` will only end when they enter the correct password, and therefore `if password != "Kearney":` is **only reached** when it definitely does. Note that `for _ in range(threshold)` would be a neater way of implementing this.

Comment: Code is unreadable in comments; Python, where formatting is (as you've already been told) important syntactically, doubly so. **Edit the question**.

Comment: Be careful you don't use tabs in python. The interpreter treats them as 8 spaces, so your code can look as though it is indented correctly when it isn't

Comment: The programme works now.

Answer (score 1):

For your if to be executed inside the while loop, you should indent it properly, this should work:

```
username = "Patrick"
password = "Kearney"

username = input("Username:")

while username != "Patrick":
    print("Please try again.")
    username = input("Enter your username again.")

password = input("Password:")
incorrect = 0
threshold = 3

while password != "Kearney":
    print("Please try again.")
    password = input("Enter your password again.")
    if password != "Kearney":
        incorrect += 1
    else:
        print("Welcome Patrick")
        incorrect = 0

    if incorrect == threshold:
        import sys
        sys.exit()
```

EDIT: as @Benjamin pointed out in the comments this is going to allow for 4 trials (1 outside the while loop and 3 inside the loop), set `threshold` to 3 or `incorrect` to 1 at the beginning to fix this.

Comment: This allows 4 trials.